# Image upload form not working with PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, file-upload

I have this form for multiple images here:
http://www.comehike.com/account/upload_hike_photos.php?hike_id=58

And when I try to get the images in the POST processing of the request, I get these messages:
Uninitialized string offset

This array does not get populated:
$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']

Any idea why?  I have a very similar form like this working here:
http://www.hikingsanfrancisco.com/account/upload_hike_photos.php?hike_id=58

But I can't quite figure out what the problem might be that makes the array of images be empty.

Comment: you can use html5 multiple upload form it saves some pain...http://rakaz.nl/2009/08/uploading-multiple-files-using-html5.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to end the name="uploadedfile" with a bracket so: "**uploadedfile[]**". Then you can go through the $_FILES['uploadedfile'] with foreach and put them in your server just like the other form.

EDIT: I've checked the source of your second link too, you have brackets in the second page you've provided. :)

Answer (score 0):

I find dumping the contents of the array often helps see the structure. Try:

```
<?php echo '<pre>'.print_r($_FILES, true).'</pre>; ?>
```

However, that said, I think Tekin was on the right path. Try using a foreach or accessing the files directly like:

```
$_FILES['uploadedfile'][0]['name']
$_FILES['uploadedfile'][1]['name']
$_FILES['uploadedfile'][2]['name']
```